# Laravel 4.1: How to paginate eloquent eager relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

There was question about old L3 eager loaded paginations, not using eloquent. But i want to use eloquent to get eager loaded relationship with pagination.

Main model: **Topic** that has one to many relationship with **Posts**,
So that one **Topic** has many **Posts**. I get all data with this function:

```
public function findById($id)
{
    return $this->topic->with('posts', 'posts.user', 'posts.user.profile')
                       ->find($id);
}
```

And later I make loop to display all results, but they are not paginated:

```
@foreach($topic->posts as $post)
... unpaginated content ...
@endforeach
```

So, i could make a workaround and select separately all posts that has $id of topic and use ->paginate() instead of ->get() and would got paginated $pots,

1. but is there possibility to use eager loaded relationship **posts** that is paginated ? And how can it be done ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To clarify something: paginating eager-loaded relationships is somewhat of a misconception. The point of eager loading is to retrieve all relationships in as few queries as you can. If you want to retrieve 10 topics, all of which have 35 posts, you will only need two queries. Sweet!

That said, paginating an eager-loaded relationship is not going to work. Consider two scenarios when eager loading happens:

1. You want to retrieve and list topics, and maybe list the first five posts for each topic. Great! Eager loading is perfect. Now, you wouldn't want to paginate the eager-loaded posts on a page like this, so it doesn't matter.
2. You load a single topic, and you want to paginate the posts for that topic. Great! Relatively easy to do. However, if you've already eager-loaded *all* posts belonging to this topic, you've just potentially retrieved a lot of extra resources that you don't need. Therefore eager loading is actually *hurting* you.

**That said**, there are two potential solutions:

Option 1: Create a custom accessor that paginates the Eloquent relationship.

```
/**
 * Paginated posts accessor. Access via $topic->posts_paginated
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
 */
public function getPostsPaginatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->posts()->paginate(10);
}
```

Pros: Paginates very easily; does not interfere with normal posts relationship.
Cons: Eager loading posts will not affect this accessor; running it will create two additional queries on top of the eager loaded query.

Option 2: Paginate the posts Collection returned by the eager-loaded relationship.

```
/**
 * Paginated posts accessor. Access via $topic->posts_paginated
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
 */
public function getPostsPaginatedAttribute()
{
    $posts = $this->posts;

    // Note that you will need to slice the correct array elements yourself.
    // The paginator class will not do that for you.

    return \Paginator::make($posts, $posts->count(), 10);
}
```

Pros: Uses the eager-loaded relationship; creates no additional queries.
Cons: Must retrieve ALL elements regardless of current page (slow); have to build the current-page elements manually.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation, Option 1 is right choice for me now. I were asking about eager loading because thought that it is only way to access posts through $topic, but Option 1 does it well and also does pagination and that is exactly what I want. Will $topic->posts_paginated->links() this work for generating links ?

Comment: Yes, it will return a `Paginator` object, just like a normal `->paginate(10)` at the end of an Eloquent query would.

Comment: The issue is that if i have 1000 comments on the database and i select it even if the attribute paginate correctly the performance go down. So there is some method for limit 10 posts for each Topic directly on Eloquent query?

Comment: What if I want to load topics, and list all the posts for the topic, but only show 10 topics at a time. Sounds like I want Topic::with('posts')->paginate(10), which is a use-case you appear to have missed.

Comment: @Benubird That's exactly what you'd want, but it's not the same thing as paginating the eager-loaded relationship. Using your example, this topic focuses on paginating the `posts` relationship, not the original topics.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at following:

```
$category = 'Laravel';

$posts = Post::with('user', 'category')->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($category) {
$query->where('name', '=', $category);
})->paginate();
```

By Zenry :
Source:http://laravel.io/forum/02-25-2014-eager-loading-with-constrains-load-post-based-on-category-name

Hope this helps

Comment: Absolutely, this worked much better for me. Instead of trying to paginate the eager loaded relationship, think about it backwards.

That way you simple grab all posts 'whereHas' the topic, and paginate over that.