# Pagination and Eager Loading in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination, eager-loading

```
My Controller method is:

$topics=Topic::with(array('subtopics'=>function($query){
            $query->orderBy('glc_subtopic_priority','asc');
        }))->with('subtopics.resources')->find($id)->paginate(1);
        return View::make('subtopics.index')->with('topics', $topics);
```

I am eager loading this and it works fine. But now I want to paginate this. I have tried 
`{{ dd($topics->toArray()) }}` and it returns me this:

```
array (size=7)
  'total' => int 2
  'per_page' => int 1
  'current_page' => int 1
  'last_page' => int 2
  'from' => int 1
  'to' => int 1
  'data' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => int 1
...........
```

The problem is when I am displaying the data. I am using

```
@foreach($topics->subtopics as $topic)
    <li>{{ $topics->glc_subtopic_name }}</li>
        {{ $topic->glc_subtopic_content }}
        @foreach($topic->resources as $resource)
        <br/>{{ $resource->glc_subtopic_resource_url }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This returns me the error:
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$subtopics`

How should I access the data in the paginated variable `$topics`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913606/laravel-4-1-how-to-paginate-eloquent-eager-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to specify the query for `subtopics`, you should eager load your `resources` models from within that query rather than eager loading `subtopics` again.

**Try this:**

```
$topics = Topic::with(['subtopics' => function($query){
    $query->with('resources')->orderBy('glc_subtopic_priority','asc');
}])->find($id)->paginate(1);

return View::make('subtopics.index', ['topics' => $topics]);
```

Comment: I did this. I want to paginate the subtopics and not the topics. For that I put paginate function inside:
Topic::with(['subtopics' => function($query){
    $query->with('resources')->orderBy('glc_subtopic_priority','asc')->paginate(1);
}])->find($id);

I am not able to access $topics->links() now. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Hhmmm, i haven't tried anything like this, but `links()` would be a method of the relationship that is paginated.  So, possibly `$topics->subtopics->links()`, but since you're only looking for 1 specific topic, why not just query your subtopics directly and pass it to your view?  `$subtopics = Subtopic::with('resources')->orderBy('glc_subtopic_priority','sac')->where('topic_id', $id)->paginate(10)` / `return View::make('subtopics.index', ['subtopics' => $subtopics]);`/ `{{ $subtopics->links() }}`

Comment: I tried with $topics->subtopics->links(). But $topics->subtopics is a collection.

I did the other way you proposed. It works now! Thank you!!