# Laravel eager loading, count before getting the result

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is weird, but somehow I would like to know if it is possible, I am creating my own pagination, and I have been looking for eager loading with pagination but some say it is still not available.

```
    //this query will get the record count
    $qry_counter = LeadsModel::with('emails','contacts','create_by_name','sources');

    //this query will get the data
    $query = LeadsModel::with('emails','contacts','create_by_name','sources');

    if(isset($inputs['page_no']) && isset($inputs['records_per_page']))
    {
        //setting pagination variables
        $paginate_start_record = ($inputs['page_no'] - 1) * $inputs['records_per_page'];

        //get the corresponding results based on the page and records per page
        $query->skip($paginate_start_record)->take($inputs['records_per_page']);
    }

    //loop through condition
    foreach($conditions as $condition)
    {
        $query->orWhere($condition[0],$condition[1],$condition[2]); 

        $qry_counter->orWhere($condition[0],$condition[1],$condition[2]);
    }

    $results_counter = $qry_counter->get()->count();

    $results = $query->get();
```

Any advise on how to optimize this code? Will it be possible to get the total records count first and then it will also return the records based on the set with skip and take? Thanks in advance

Comment: You write in your question *"some say it is still not available"* - can you please provide reference for that statement? And would it be a requirement for you to have it available?

Comment: Laravel has [awesome pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) built right in. Why build your own?

Comment: Maybe I understand it differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913606/laravel-4-1-how-to-paginate-eloquent-eager-relationship I am sorry if that is the case though.. however, coming back to the question above, is that possible?