# Laravel paginator doesn't work properly

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination, forum

The laravel paginator does work, but not good in my case.

So I have a forum with comments and the paginator must display when there are **more than 10** comments on that page.

So I have a topic that has more than 10 comments and then it works fine on that page, but when I go to another page, he does take the pagination of the **most** comments. That is not what I want.

> Here are some screens and code:

[image: pic1]

Here are there more than 10 comments, so it is good that it displays the paginator. The strange thing here is that it only shows **2** comments and not 10.

Here is another topic with just 8 comments, so the pagination shouldn't display anything:

[image: scr 2]

But as you can see, it does show the paginator....

My code look like this:

> Controller:

```
public function thread($title)
    {
        $thread = Thread::where('title', '=', str_replace('Thread-', '',str_replace('-', ' ', $title)))->first();

        $usercolor = DB::table('threads')
                                ->join('user', 'threads.uid', '=', 'user.id')
                                ->join('role', 'user.role_id', '=', 'role.id')
                                ->where('threads.uid', '=', $thread->uid)
                                ->first();

        $usertitle = DB::table('threads')
                                ->join('user', 'threads.uid', '=', 'user.id')
                                ->where('threads.uid', '=', $thread->uid)
                                ->first();

        $comments = Comment::orderBy('posted_at', 'asc')
                                ->where('deleted_at', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                                ->with('user.role')
                                ->paginate(10);

        if (!$thread) {
            return die('bestaat niet!');
        }else{

        return View::make('thread')->with('threads', $thread)
                                   ->with('comments', $comments)
                                   ->with('usercolor', $usercolor)
                                   ->with('usertitle', $usertitle);

        }

    }
```

> View:

```
@include('globs.header')

<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>


@if(Request::get('page', 1) == 1)
<div class="panel panel-default" id="a9">
  <div class="panel-heading">     
    <div class="panel-title">{{ $threads->title }}  

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body thread-row"> 

    <div class="row thread-row">

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center userblock">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail avatar" src="./public/img/avatar.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="55px;" width="55px">   
        <div class="push_bottom_5" style="color:{{ $usercolor->colour }};"><strong>{{ $threads->username }}</strong></div>
        <div class="push_bottom_5"><small>{{ $usertitle->usertitle }}</small></div>
        <div class="label label-default" style="background-color:{{ $usercolor->colour }};">{{ $usercolor->name }}</div>

        <div class="push_bottom_5">
          @if($usercolor->id == '1')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($usercolor->id == '2')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($usercolor->id == '3')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($usercolor->id == '4')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($usercolor->id == '5')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($usercolor->id >= '6')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @endif
        </div> 

        <div class="text-muted text-left"><small>Total Posts:&nbsp; 66</small></div>    
        <div class="text-muted text-left"><small>Joined&nbsp; 05-11-2014</small></div>



        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="text-muted"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </span><small>
        <span>Posted:</span> {{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($threads->date_posted)) }}</small></div>   
      </div>    

      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="content_body"><p>{{ Helper::Filter(BBCode::parse($threads->message)) }}</p>

</div>
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="panel-footer clearfix">   
    <div class="pull-right">  
      <!-- acties -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Aanpassen</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Quote</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Verwijder</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Rapporteer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- end of the topic -->
</div>
@endif


<!-- begin of comments -->
@foreach($comments as $comment)
@if($comment->tid == $threads->tid)

<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>


<div class="panel panel-default" id="a9">

  <div class="panel-body thread-row"> 

    <div class="row thread-row">

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center userblock">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail avatar" src="./public/img/avatar.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="55px;" width="55px">   
        <div class="push_bottom_5" style="color:{{ $comment->user->role->colour }};"><strong>{{ $comment->username }}</strong></div>
        <div class="push_bottom_5"><small>{{ $comment->user->usertitle }}</small></div>
        <div class="label label-default" style="background-color:{{ $comment->user->role->colour }};">{{ $comment->user->role->name }}</div>

        <div class="push_bottom_5">
          @if($comment->user->role->id == '1')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($comment->user->role->id == '2')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($comment->user->role->id == '3')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($comment->user->role->id == '4')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($comment->user->role->id == '5')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @elseif($comment->user->role->id >= '6')
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          @endif
        </div>

        <div class="text-muted text-left"><small>Total Posts:&nbsp; 66</small></div>    
        <div class="text-muted text-left"><small>Joined&nbsp; 05-11-2014</small></div>



        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="text-muted"><span class="hidden-md "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span><small><span>Posted:</span> {{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($comment->posted_at)) }}</small></div>   
      </div>    

      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="content_body"><p>{{ Helper::Filter(BBCode::parse($comment->comment)) }}</p>

</div>
        <div class="clerafix">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="panel-footer clearfix">   
    <div class="pull-right">
    <!-- acties -->
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Aanpassen</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> Quote</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Verwijder</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Rapporteer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
@endif
@endforeach

<!-- end of comments -->


@if(Auth::check())
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="a9">
          <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Snelle reactie plaatsen</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">

          {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'SubmitComment')) }}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $threads->tid }}" name="tid">
            {{ Honeypot::generate('spamprt', 'time') }}
                <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" col="250" rows="5" placeholder="Typ uw bericht..."></textarea>

                <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" type="submit" name="action">
            Reageer
            </button>
          {{ Form::close() }}

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif


<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">{{ $comments->links() }}</div>



</div>
</div>

@include('globs.footer')
```

I hope you guys will understand my problem and are be able to find a perfect solution with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you always retrieve *all* comments. I can also see this in your template, where you wrap your code in `@if($comment->tid == $threads->tid)` within your `foreach`.

This means that later in your template, where you retrieve the pagination links, it will retrieve the links for *all* comments, but not all comments are shown in the page, since you filter them manually in the loop.

Query the comments like

```
$comments = Comment::orderBy('posted_at', 'asc')
    ->where('deleted_at', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    ->where('tid', $threads->tid) // it's about this line!
    ->with('user.role')
    ->paginate(10);
```

**Note:**
Above should provide a solution for your problem, but as an extra, you could also look into [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships). As an addition, this answer on SO ["Laravel 4.1: How to paginate eloquent eager relationship?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924498/2433843) (Since you tagged your post with Laravel-4) has some nice arguments on how to approach this efficiently.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I didn't think so far :$