# How to paginate the sub objects or Advise me to handle this in a better way

Tags: php, api, laravel, pagination

I am using Laravel Luman to build an API for a news app. So far no issue with the API and the way it gives the results, but to improve the mobile experience i am planning to add pagination for the results. I tried several ways and could not figure out to do it. Can anyone can suggest me a better way to tackle this issue?

```
    [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "News",
        count: 400, // 400 posts available
        posts: [
        {
           id: 6,
           title: "Quick brown fox",
        }, 
        {
           id: 9,
           title: "umps over lazy dog",
        }, 
    ]
```

My requirement is adding a pagination for the post object. Please find the following Image for the reference
[image]

Comment: While googling I found a suggestion for similar question as mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913606/laravel-4-1-how-to-paginate-eloquent-eager-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do the pagination for the eager loading.

```
$category = Category::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
$posts = $category->posts()->paginate();

// then pass both variables to the view
return View::make('some.view', compact('category', 'posts');

// and loop through the products directly
@foreach ($posts as $post)
```

You can also do

```
$category= Category::with('posts' => function ($q) {
   $q->paginate(10);
}])->whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
```

But using the second methodology, you wouldn't be able to do the render links.

Comment: I know there is a pagination helper in Laravel but my question is totally different for to answer

Comment: Category::with('posts')->where('category_id', $id)->first()

Comment: According to the screenshot that query returns 400 posts, hence I want to paginate the post object.

Comment: So you mean you want to paginate the eager loading. Right?

Comment: Yeah indeed, I want to paginate the eager loading

Comment: While googling I found a suggestion for similar question as mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913606/laravel-4-1-how-to-paginate-eloquent-eager-relationship