# Laravel 5 how paginate with hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a relationship this like;

```
public function foods() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\food\food', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

My controller file content;

```
$datas = food_category::where('slug', $slug)->with('foods')->paginate(12);
```

But incoming datas in there all datas and this is causing bad performance.   I want to paginate apply relationship datas.

Comment: Do you want to apply pagination on categories or foods?

Comment: I would advise against thinking about paginating eager-loaded relationships. I wrote about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913606/laravel-4-1-how-to-paginate-eloquent-eager-relationship?rq=1

Comment: I want to apply foods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paginate `foods`, try adding a separate method for that:

Model:

```
class food_category
{
    public function getFoodsPaginatedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->foods()->paginate(12);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$datas = food_category::where('slug', $slug)->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)
    @foreach ($data->foods_paginated as $food)
        {{ $food->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: There is a minus of this method, Eager Loading does not work. How to use ->with() ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass paginated collection to the view:

```
//view
@foreach ($datas as $data)
    // do what you need
@endforeach
//link
{{$datas->links()}}
```